# Moving to synchronisation via forest without removing users or re-adding users

Tags: azure-active-directory, synchronization

If users once synced with Azure AD Connect Cloud Provisioning can be moved to synchronization via Forest trust without having to remove and re-add the users?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud provisioning can be used to sync from multiple Active Directory forests. In the multi-forest environment, all the references (example, manager) need to be within the domain. Users and groups  must be represented only once across all forests.

Kindly check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-provisioning/plan-cloud-provisioning-topologies) for Azure AD connect cloud provisioning supported topologies to get detailed information about this